# How JpaPagingItemReader works?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to implement a reader java class: **UserReader extends JpaPagingItemReader**
this reader should execute a query String: "query_string" and return the result to the processor.

I've searched in the net and I couldn't understand how JpaPagingItemReader works?
normally I shoud find something like this:

```
package com.UserReader;
public class UserReader extends JpaPagingItemReader<User> {
            @Override
               public User read()
               {
                 read();
               }
        }

<bean id="userReader"
        class="com.userReader">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="queryString"
            value="myQuery" />
    </bean>
```

...step declaration reader="userReader"

But actually, I found the same java class, but with a non understable xml config (no reference to com.UserReader in spring beans but a bean with class : org.spring...jpaPagingItemReader and id: userReader), how spring batch knows that jpaPagingItemReader refers to the com.userReader class (we suppose that we can have many readers)? is it by the id of the bean?

Comment: You shouldn't need a custom reader. Just a query for the `JpaPagingItemReader`. There is no need in subclassing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but indeed, I need to define a custom reader because the query will always return one element (it searchs the last inserted user) so I have to implement an algorithme to tell to my batch to stop after just one execution. Otherwise, the step will loop infinitely (reader will always returns a single result).

Comment: No you don't... Write a correct query which does what you want it to do (return the last inserted user).

Comment: In fact if I do what you propose, I will always obtain a result in the reader therefore it won't stop (The reader should return null the second time)

Comment: Why do you even use a `JpaPagingItemReader`? Just implement `ItemReader` yourself... You have no use for the `JpaPagingItemReader` if it needs to return the last inserted user... (feels also if you are using the w rong tool for the job).